# Angular 4. Как получить модель юзера и обработать до начала загрузки дочерних компонентов?

Tags: javascript, angular2

Как получить модель юзера и обработать до начала загрузки дочерних компонентов?

Дочерние компоненты подгружаются через **lazy loading**.
Я подумал что можно это реализовать через **resolve** который подтягивает данные с сервера и сохраняет в синглтон сервисе **UserService**. Что бы **resolve** вызывался только один раз я реализовал роутер следующим образом:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: AppComponent,
        resolve: {
            user: UserResolver
        },
        children: [
            {path: '', loadChildren: './client/client.module#ClientModule'},
            {path: 'admin', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule', canActivate: [STSPAdminGuard]},
            {path: 'account', loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule'}
        ]
    },
    {path: '**', redirectTo: '404', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: '404', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];
```

По идее пока resolve не вернет данные компонент не должен подгружаться. Соответственно в дочерних компонентах я должен получить модель юзера через

```
route.snapshot.data['user']
```

или через сервис в котором я ее сохранил. Но значения snapshot или сервиса при загрузке для дочерних компонентов **undefined**.

Такое поведение наводит на мысль что дочерние компоненты загружаются асинхронно.

Как сделать так что бы дочерние компоненты загружались после того как загрузилась модель юзера?

Comment: где находилась эта строчка? `route.snapshot.data['user']`

Comment: В AppComponent сохраняется в сервис. И пробывал в canActivate(STSPAdminGuard) делать проверку. Получается что когда я хожу по рутерам то все норм. Но если я например в админке и перезагружаю страницу, то значение undefined и canActivate не проходит.

Comment: нужен более комплексный пример кода, а именно где и как ты пытаешься достать user

Comment: `route.snapshot.data['user']` в конструкторе?

Comment: И в конструкторе и за пределами и в ngOnInit. Resolve не помогает потому что он ждет когда можно отрисовать компонент а не когда можно загружать дочерние компоненты. Как загрузить дочерние компоненты отложенно?

Comment: можешь поставить на дочерний компонент ngIf и передавать true когда ты получишь юзера

Comment: Я бы предложил воспользоваться ``ui-router``'ом. В базовом примере как раз есть реализация того, что с начала загружается юзер, а только потом грузиться уже всё остальное.

Comment: @SergeyRogachev, если что, речь идет об Angular4, а не о первом

Comment: @Grundy, если что есть ``ui-router`` для Angular4 ;)

Answer (score 1):

В общем я заюзал CanActivate. Resolve в данной ситуации не подходит. Так как он сразу загружает все модули и ждет разрешения отрендерить компонент. Так же попробовал CanLoad но он работает только на lazy loading модулях.

Роутер:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent,
    canActivate: [UserActivate],
    children: [
        {path: '', loadChildren: './client/client.module#ClientModule'},
        {path: 'admin', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule', canActivate: [STSPAdminGuard]},
        {path: 'account', loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule'},
    ]
},
{path: '**', redirectTo: '404', pathMatch: 'full'},
{path: '404', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
```

];

CanActivate класс:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserActivate implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private userService: UserService, 
                private http: Http) {}

canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.http.get('api/user/me')
        .map(res => {
            this.userService.initUser(res.json());
            return true;
        })
        .catch((response: Response) => {
                return Observable.of(true);
            }
        )
    }
}
```